# Only run if email has attachment

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment, email-attachments

I want the below code to run when a specific subject appears in an email.
Also to only run if that email has an attachment.

Outlook ignores the attachment part of the rule, and tries to run the code even if the attachment is not there (it seems to only care about the subject).

How do I incorporate a check for attachment in the code?

```vb
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsThenOpen(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oMail As Variant
    Dim oReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim StrBody As String
    Dim oRep As MailItem
    
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    Dim Att As String
    Dim Attname As String
    Dim sht As Object
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim s As String
    
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim XLApp As Object
    Dim XlWK As Object
    Dim strPaste  As Variant
     
    Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set oNs = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        
    Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With XLApp
        .Visible = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Workbooks.Open ("C:\Directory\data.xlsx")
        .Workbooks.Open ("C:\Directory\WB.xlsb")
    End With

    Dim strText As String
    strText = ".xls"
    sSaveFolder = "C:\Directory\TPS_Reports\"

    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        If InStr(1, oAttachment.FileName, strText) > 0 Then
            oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.FileName
            Attname = oAttachment.FileName
            Att = sSaveFolder & oAttachment.FileName
            Exit For
        End If
    
    Next oAttachment
    Set oAttachment = Nothing
    
    XLApp.Workbooks.Open (Att)
    XLApp.Visible = True
    XLApp.Run ("WB.XLSB!MacroName")
    
    Set sht = XLApp.Workbooks(Attname).ActiveSheet
    
    Set Rng = sht.UsedRange
    
    s = "<table border=1 bordercolor=black cellspacing=0>"
    For rw = Rng.Row To Rng.Rows.Count
        s = s & "<tr>"
        For col = Rng.Column To Rng.Columns.Count
            s = s & "<td>" & sht.Cells(rw, col) & "</td>"
        Next
        s = s & "</tr>"
    Next
    s = s & "</table>"

    Set oRep = MItem.ReplyAll

    With oRep
        StrBody = "Hello"
        .HTMLBody = s
        .Send
    End With

    With XLApp
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    
    XLApp.Workbooks(Attname).Save
    XLApp.Quit

    With XLApp
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: If you cannot find/get an answer on superuser.com then you can add `If MItem.Attachments.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub` to the code.

Comment: Thank you!  Where should that be placed in the code??

Comment: @MarkFisher Adding that line as the first line should be fine (below `Public Sub SaveAttachmentsThenOpen(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)`)

Comment: I added in the code, and it still is not working properly.  When i just ran a test the excel workbooks still opened, and then got an error because there was not an attachment in outlook to open.

Comment: The rule thinks there is an attachment. `MItem.Attachments.Count` is not zero. The conclusion is there is an attachment. What line generates an error and what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for the mail to be in the inbox before checking for the attachment.

Code for the ThisOutlookSession module

Restart Outlook or run `Application_Startup` manually.

```vb
Private WithEvents myItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim myInbox  As folder
    
    Set myInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub myItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is mailItem Then
        If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            SaveAttachmentsThenOpen Item
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub test()
    myItems_ItemAdd ActiveInspector.currentItem
End Sub
```